# Why do React Native stack trace and Debugger UI not show the exact problem JS file?

Tags: android, reactjs, android-studio, react-native, debugging

I purposely commented out a line in my react native code to see if I would have been able to find the error in the stack trace or debugger UI, but it doesn't show the exact file where I commented out the line.

If this were a real situation where I was trying to debug a problem, I wouldn't know which exact file was the problem.

How can I modify my debugging tools to show me the exact problem file?  Should I be using a different debugging tool?

[react native trace and debugger not showing exact problem file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5xnb.png)